# How to get a panel vertical scroll bar working (Appears but does not do anything)?

Tags: c#, scroll, scrollbar, panel, vertical-scrolling

I have added a scroll bar programmatically to a panel in my form, however when i run the application the scroll bar doesn't do anything.

How do I get it to scroll up and down the panel?

Much appreciated.

```
pnlGantt.Visible = true;
ScrollBar vScrollBar1 = new VScrollBar();
vScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
vScrollBar1.Scroll += (sender, e) => { pnlGantt.VerticalScroll.Value = vScrollBar1.Value; };
pnlGantt.Controls.Add(vScrollBar1);
```

Panel:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What is your content you want to scroll placed in? Is it a StackPanel? Your scrollbar does not know about the size of the content/panel it is supposed to control.

Try to put your content (the pnlGantt) inside a ScrollViewer in XAML instead. Right now you are placing the scrollbar inside the pnlGantt.